# Passing a Bash exit code into another script from .bashrc

Tags: bash, exit-code

hey guys I'm having an issue passing a exit code from my ~/.bashrc file into another script continually (as in, a new code each time a command is executed). I currently have the following

.bashrc

```
generateFlag() 
{
    local flag="$?" ; PS1=''
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=generateFlag

. ~/.scipts/prompt.sh $flag
```

My prompt script is pretty much this

```
echo $1
```

Anyone know a way to get this working??

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? First of all: the `local flag` declaration is local to the function `generateFlag` so it's not visible outside it. That means that `$flag` has no value after the call. To make it visible outside, after the call, just drop the `local` keyword.

Comment: I'm trying to continually echo the status codes / exit codes of commands inside of a script without using PS1 from bashrc, or to create PS1 inside of bashrc and pass in exit codes

Comment: I'm still confused. Do you wish to put the exit code of the most recently run command in your shell prompt? Or the exit status of some other script? What's the expected behaviour?

Comment: Expected behaviour is of the most recently run command, that will be displayed by the script

Comment: Here this might help a little: https://github.com/ehime/bash-git-prompt/commit/656578e9a6e372e8fafbbd64c46ab2919f61af62#diff-0e78b0fccb3c708b2e3176fdc9cc9746

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.bashrc :

```
# some code before
export FLAG=$?
```

exec script :

```
~/.scripts/prompt.sh $FLAG
```